# Ray Tracing GLSL - Sphere stretching when position is moved

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, glsl, raytracing

Me and a friend are building a Ray Tracer but we have run into problems as you can see in the pickture.
When we render the sphere with the position of vec3(0,0,0) then it renders it as a circle but otherwise it stretches.
[image]
What are we doing wrong?

I thought it would be best to paste all our code so here it is. I hope I commented it well.

```
//
1| // RayTracer.glsl ~ A Raytracer that's being executed as Compute Shader
2| // Date: 11-09-2014
3| // Inspired by: Stanislaw Eppinger ~ https://github.com/StanEpp/OpenGL_Raytracing
4| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
5| // Type: Entry point
6| //
7| 
8| // Using at least 4.3 to ensure Compute Shader support.
9| #version 430 core
10| 
11| // Declaring the local workgroup size.
12| layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;
13| 
14| 
15| //---------------------------
16| // Libraries
17| //---------------------------
18| //
19| // Math.glsl ~ A Library with Mathematical functions
20| // Date: 11-09-2014
21| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
22| // Type: Library
23| //
24| 
25| // Solves a equation with the ABC formula.
26| bool SolveQuadratic(float a, float b, float c, out float x0, out float x1)
27| {
28|     // Calculate the Discriminant.
29|     float D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
30|     
31|     // No solution exists if D is smaller then 0.
32|     if(D < 0)
33|     {
34|         return false;
35|     }
36| 
37|     // If D == 0 only 1 solution exists.
38|     if (D == 0)
39|     {
40|         x0 = -0.5 * b / a;
41|         x1 = -0.5 * b / a;
42|     }
43| 
44|     // If D is higher then 1, two solutions exist.
45|     else 
46|     {
47|         float q;
48|         if(b > 0)
49|             q = -0.5 * (b + sqrt(D));
50|         else
51|             q = -0.5 * (b - sqrt(D));
52|         
53|         x0 = q / a;
54|         x1 = c / q;
55|     }
56| 
57|     return true;
58| }
59| //
60| // Screen.glsl ~ Represents the current screen with the width and height. 
61| // Date: 11-09-2014
62| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
63| // Type: Library
64| //
65| 
66| struct Screen
67| {
68|     uint width;     // Width of the Screen
69|     uint height;    // Height of the Screen
70| };
71| //
72| // Camera.glsl ~ Represents a Camera and it's corresponding functions
73| // Date: 11-09-2014
74| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
75| // Type: Library
76| //
77| 
78| struct Camera
79| {
80|     mat4x4 C2W;     // Camera to World matrix
81|     float FOVx;     // The horizontal Field of View in radians. Tan(DegreesX / 2 * 180 * PI)
82|     float FOVy;     // The vertical Field of View in radians. Tan(DegreesY / 2 * 180 * PI)
83| };
84| 
85| //
86| // Ray.glsl ~ Describes a Ray structure which is used to track the light.
87| // Date: 11-09-2014
88| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
89| // Type: Library
90| //
91| 
92| // Forward references
93| struct Camera;
94| struct Screen;
95| 
96| struct Ray
97| {
98|     vec3 origin;
99|     vec3 direction;
100| };
101| 
102| Ray GetPrimaryRay(in uint x, in uint y, in Camera camera, in Screen screen)
103| {
104|    Ray primary;
105| 
106|    float halfWidth = float(screen.width) / 2.0f;
107|    float halfHeight = float(screen.height) / 2.0f;
108|    float aspectRatio = screen.width / screen.height;
109| 
110|    float Mappedx = camera.FOVx * ((float(x) - halfWidth + 0.5f) / halfWidth);
111|    float Mappedy = camera.FOVy * ((halfHeight - float(y) - 0.5f) / halfHeight);
112| 
113|    primary.direction = normalize(Mappedx * camera.C2W[0].xyz + Mappedy * camera.C2W[1].xyz + -1 * camera.C2W[2].xyz);
114|    primary.origin = camera.C2W[3].xyz;
115|    return primary;
116| };
117| //
118| // Sphere.glsl ~ Describing Sphere and it's corresponding methods.
119| // Date: 11-09-2014
120| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
121| // Type: Library
122| //
123| 
124| #define ERROR_MARGIN 0.01f
125| 
126| struct Sphere
127| {
128|    vec3 position;
129|    float radius;
130| };
131| 
132| 
133| bool IntersectSphere(in Sphere sphere, in Ray ray, out float projection)
134| {
135|    // Create a vector from the Ray origin to the center of the Sphere.
136|     vec3 RS = sphere.position - ray.origin;
137| 
138|    // Calculate the Radius Squared for performance reasons.
139|    float Rsquared = sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
140| 
141|    // Project the center of the Sphere on Ray.
142|    float ProjCR = dot(RS, ray.direction);
143| 
144|    // Calculate the length from the center to the projection.
145|    float Dsquared = dot(RS,RS) - ProjCR * ProjCR;
146| 
147|    // If the length from the center to the projection is bigger then the radius, the ray misses.
148|     if (Dsquared > Rsquared)
149|        return false;
150|    
151|    // Calculate the distance from the projCR to the point on the square.
152|    float ProjInt = sqrt(Rsquared - Dsquared);
153|     float x0 = ProjCR - ProjInt;
154|     float x1 = ProjCR + ProjInt;
155| 
156|    if(x0 < ERROR_MARGIN)
157|    {
158|        if(x1 < ERROR_MARGIN)
159|            return false;
160|        else
161|        {
162|            projection = x1;
163|            return true;
164|        }
165|    }
166|    projection = x0;
167|    return true;
168| }
169| 
170| 
171| //
172| // Material.glsl ~ Represents a material.
173| // Date: 11-09-2014
174| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
175| // Type: Library
176| //
177| 
178| struct Material
179| {
180|    vec3 color;         // Value's between 0 and 1.0f
181|    float opacity;
182| };
183| //
184| // Light.glsl ~ Describing a Light structure and the associated reflections.
185| // Date: 11-09-2014
186| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
187| // Type: Library
188| // Knowledge: Most of the information is from the following paper: http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/2006--degreve--reflection_refraction.pdf
189| //
190| 
191| struct Light
192| {
193|    vec3 position;
194|    vec3 color;         // Value's between 0 and 255 
195|    float intensity;
196| };
197| 
198| // RI_1: The Refractive index of the material the ray is coming from.
199| // RI_2: The Refractive index of the material the ray is entering.
200| // I: The normalized incoming ray.
201| // N: The normalized normal of the surface.
202| 
203| vec3 GetReflection(vec3 I, vec3 N)
204| {
205|    return I - 2 * dot(I,N) * N;
206| }
207| 
208| vec3 Refract(vec3 I, vec3 N, float RI_1, float RI_2)
209| {
210|    float X = (RI_1/RI_2);
211|    float SinTSquared = X * X * (1 - dot(I,N)*dot(I,N));
212|    if(SinTSquared <= 1)
213|        return (RI_1/RI_2 * I) + (RI_1/RI_2 * dot(I,N) - sqrt(1 - SinTSquared)) * N;
214|    else
215|        return vec3(0,0,0);
216| }
217| 
218| // Calculates how much light is reflected at a specific angle related to the normal vector.
219| float Fresnel_Unpolarised(vec3 I, vec3 N, float RI_1, float RI_2)
220| {
221|    float X = RI_1 / RI_2;
222|    float CosI = -dot(N, I);
223|    float SinT2 = X * X * (1.0 - CosI * CosI);
224| 
225|    // If the Critical Angle is reached no light is refracted.
226|    if(SinT2 > 1.0)
227|        return 1.0;
228| 
229|    float CosT = sqrt(1.0 - SinT2);
230|    float Rorthogonal = (RI_1 * CosI - RI_2 * CosT) / (RI_1 * CosI + RI_2 * CosT);
231|    float Rparallel = (RI_2 * CosI - RI_1 * CosT) / (RI_2 * CosI + RI_1 * CosT);
232|    return (Rorthogonal * Rorthogonal + Rparallel * Rparallel) / 2;
233| }
234| 
235| float Fresnel_SPolarised(vec3 I, vec3 N, float RI_1, float RI_2)
236| {
237|    return 0;
238| }
239| 
240| float Fresnel_PPolarised(vec3 I, vec3 N, float RI_1, float RI_2)
241| {
242|    return 0;
243| }
244| 
245| float Schlick(vec3 I, vec3 N, float RI_1, float RI_2)
246| {
247|    return 0;
248| }
249| //
250| // Stack.glsl ~ Contains a Stack and StackEntry structure for holding multiple rays to be evaluated.
251| // Date: 11-09-2014
252| // Authors: Christian Veenman, Tom van Dijkhuizen
253| // Type: Library
254| //
255| 
256| #define MAX_STACK_SIZE 64
257| 
258| struct StackEntry
259| {
260|    uint depth;
261|    float fraction;
262|    Ray ray;
263| };
264| 
265| struct Stack
266| {
267|    int current;
268|    StackEntry entries[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
269| };
270| 
271| // Pushes an element on the stack.
272| void Push(inout Stack stack, in StackEntry entry)
273| {
274|    stack.entries[stack.current] = entry;
275|    stack.current = stack.current + 1;
276| }
277| 
278| // Pops an element from the stack.
279| StackEntry Pop(inout Stack stack)
280| {
281|    stack.current = stack.current - 1;
282|    return stack.entries[stack.current];
283| }
284| 
285| // Checks if the stack is empty
286| bool isEmpty(inout Stack stack)
287| {
288|    if(stack.current == 0)
289|        return true;
290|    else
291|        return false;
292| }
293| 
294| 
295| //---------------------------
296| // Defines
297| //---------------------------
298| #define FARPLANE 100000f
299| 
300| 
301| //---------------------------
302| // Uniforms and Buffers
303| //---------------------------
304| //uniform Camera camera;
305| //uniform Screen screen;
306| //uniform uint maxreflections;
307| 
308| layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer PixelBuffer
309| {
310|    uint pixels[];
311| };
312| 
313| 
314| //---------------------------
315| // Test Data
316| //---------------------------
317| Sphere spheres[1];
318| Light lights[1];
319| Screen screen;
320| Camera camera;
321| Stack stack;
322| uint maxdepth;
323| 
324| 
325| //---------------------------
326| // Utility / Main functions
327| //---------------------------
328| uint PackColor(in uvec4 color)
329| {
330|    uint value = (color.a << 24);           // Alpha
331|    value = value + (color.r << 16);        // Red
332|    value = value + (color.g << 8);         // Green
333|    value = value + (color.b);              // Blue
334|     return value;
335| }
336| 
337| void InitTest()
338| {
339|    maxdepth = 3;
340|    lights[0] = Light(vec3(0, 0, 3), vec3(255, 255, 255), 50);
341| 
342|    spheres[0].position = vec3(0,3,-20);
343|    spheres[0].radius = 20;
344| 
345|    camera.C2W = mat4x4(vec4(1,0,0,0), vec4(0,1,0,0), vec4(0,0,1,0), vec4(0,0,0,1));
346|    camera.FOVx = 90;
347|    camera.FOVy = 90;
348| 
349|    screen.width = 1280;
350|    screen.height = 1024;
351| }
352| 
353| // Routine for Intersection of all objects in the scene.
354| bool Intersect(in Ray ray, out vec3 P, out vec3 N, out int ID)
355| {
356|    //-------------------------------------------------------------
357|    // #1: For every object find the closest intersection,
358|    // TODO: For now only spheres.
359|    //-------------------------------------------------------------
360|    
361|    float closestProjection = FARPLANE;
362|    ID = -1;
363|    for(int i = 0; i < spheres.length(); i++)
364|    {
365|        float projection = 0;
366|        if(IntersectSphere(spheres[i], ray, projection))
367|            if(projection < closestProjection)
368|            {
369|                closestProjection = projection;
370|                ID = i;
371|            }
372|    }
373|    
374|    // No intersection is found.
375|    if(ID == -1)
376|        return false;
377|    else
378|    {
379|        // Calculate the point of intersection.
380|        P = ray.origin + closestProjection * ray.direction;
381| 
382|        // Calculate the normal of the intersection point.
383|        N = normalize(P - spheres[ID].position);
384|        return true;
385|    }
386| }
387| 
388| vec3 CastShadowRay(in vec3 P, in Light light)
389| {
390|    vec3 P2L = light.position - P;
391|    float Length = length(P2L);
392|    Ray shadowRay = Ray(P, normalize(P2L));
393| 
394|    // Check if the light ray is obstructed.
395|    vec3 Point;
396|    vec3 Normal;
397|    int ID;
398|    if(Intersect(shadowRay, Point, Normal, ID))
399|        return vec3(0, 0, 0);
400|    else
401|    {
402|        // Calculate the amount of light (Light decreased per 1/(distance^2))
403|        return light.color * light.intensity * 1/(Length*Length);
404|    }
405| }
406| 
407| // Returns the Direct Lighting at a given point
408| vec3 DirectLighting(in vec3 P)
409| {
410|    vec3 color = vec3(0,0,0);
411|    for(uint i = 0; i < lights.length(); i++)
412|        color += CastShadowRay(P, lights[i]);
413| 
414|    return color;
415| }
416| 
417| // The Main Ray Tracing Routine.
418| void main()
419| {
420|    //----------------------
421|    // Ray Tracer Algoritm
422|    //----------------------
423|    InitTest();
424|    
425|    // #0: Set some global variables.
426|    vec3 color = vec3(0, 0, 0);
427|    uint x = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
428|    uint y = gl_GlobalInvocationID.y;
429| 
430| 
431|    // #1: Construct Primary Ray and push it on the stack.
432|    Ray primary = GetPrimaryRay(x, y, camera, screen);
433|    Push(stack, StackEntry(0, 1.0f, primary));
434| 
435|    // #2: While the stack is not empty, keep popping rays from the stack which need to be evaluated.
436|    while(!isEmpty(stack))
437|    {
438|        // #3: Pop a ray and cast it into the scene.
439|        StackEntry entry = Pop(stack);
440|        vec3 P;                 // The Point of Intersection.
441|        vec3 N;                 // The (normalized) Normal of Intersection.
442|        int ID;                 // The ID of the Intersected Object.
443| 
444|        // #4: Check if the ray intersects with an object in the scene.
445|        if(Intersect(primary, P, N, ID))
446|        {
447|            // #5: Check if new rays result from this ray.
448|            if(entry.depth < maxdepth)
449|            {
450|                // #6: Calculate Reflection ray. TODO Calculate fraction
451|                //vec3 reflection = reflect(entry.ray.direction, N);
452|                //Push(stack, StackEntry(entry.depth + 1, entry.fraction /2, Ray(P, reflection)));
453| 
454|                // #7: TODO: Calculate Refraction ray.
455|            }
456| 
457|            // #8: Calculate the direct lighting from incoming light sources.
458|            // Direct Lighting is disabled for now.
459|            color += entry.fraction * 255;
460|        }
461|    }
462| 
463|    if(color.r > 255 && color.r > color.b && color.r > color.g)
464|    {
465|        color /= color.r;
466|        color *= 255;
467|    }
468|    else if(color.b > 255 && color.b > color.r && color.b > color.g)
469|    {
470|        color /= color.b;
471|        color *= 255;
472|    }
473|    else if(color.g > 255)
474|    {
475|        color /= color.g;
476|        color *= 255;
477|    }
478| 
479|    uint RGBA = PackColor(uvec4(color.r, color.g, color.b, 255));
480|    pixels[(screen.height - y - 1)*screen.width + x] = RGBA;
481| }
```

---

EDITS:

- When we move the camera 5 backwards as requested by Freddy(such that it's on 0,0,5) we get the following result:
  [image: When we move the camera backwards]
- When we use the following testdata as requested by Basic:
  lights[0] = Light(vec3(0, 5, 20), vec3(255, 255, 255), 50);

  spheres[0].position = vec3(0,0,0);
  spheres[0].radius = 20;

  camera.C2W = mat4x4(vec4(1,0,0,0), vec4(0,1,0,0), vec4(0,0,1,0), vec4(0,5,20,1));
  we get:
  [image: At origin]

---

Comment: Forgot to add the pickture! I will now!

Comment: Is the shape rendered always either a perfect circle or the distortion shown above? Or does the distortion increase as the sphere moves away from the origin?

Comment: curious, what happens if you move the camera back 5 units on the z-axis? Does your problem disapear?

Comment: *Thanks for adding the line numbers!* Now nobody has a chance to simply test out your code!

Comment: Based purely on the image, it looks like the distance being used in the hit/miss is the squared distance from the origin, not the center of the sphere (think of the middle of a fish-eye lens). Since a sphere at the origin would show no distortion, it's not until you move it that the error is apparent. I'd look somewhere around `float Dsquared = dot(RS,RS) - ProjCR * ProjCR;`. Conversely, try keeping the sphere at the origin and pointing the camera off-centre. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: Thanks for responding everyone!, We'll work on it Wenesday again so I hope to respond at least then! I will let you know if it works! Otherwise I owe you:P

Comment: @Freddy I added your request as a pickture! And this is the result I got!

Comment: @Basic We worked on the project again and we tried your request with the data seen in the edit. Furthermore: We tried a different Sphere Ray intersection method and we got exact the same result. (The algoritm was kind of litterly copied from the internet) I am thinking it might go wrong when constructing a primary ray but I just can't seem to get what is going wrong... hope you can help!

Answer (score 2):

I have done some work with ray tracing on CUDA and in my solutions I use the following code for pin hole camera primary rays generation:

```
routine void emitpinh(float2 wh, float2 pd, float *_hb, int offset = 0)
{
    float4 vmt[4] = { GetViewMatrixCol0(), GetViewMatrixCol1(), GetViewMatrixCol2(), GetViewMatrixCol3() };

    float4 u = make_float4(vmt[1].x, vmt[1].y, vmt[1].z, 0.0f);
    float4 d = make_float4(vmt[2].x, vmt[2].y, vmt[2].z, 0.0f) / tanf(deg2rad(GetFovY() * 0.5f));
    float4 r = make_float4(cross(make_float3(d.x, d.y, d.z), make_float3(u.x, u.y, u.z)), 0.0f);
    float4 o = make_float4(vmt[3].x, vmt[3].y, vmt[3].z, -1.0f);
    uint3 p = GetGlobalThreadIdx();

    float3 whas = make_float3(blockDim.x * gridDim.x, blockDim.y * gridDim.y, 0.0f);
    whas.z = wh.y / wh.x;

    u = normalize(u);
    r = normalize(r);

    float2 uv = make_float2(p.x / whas.x, p.y / whas.y) - 0.5f;
    uv.y *= whas.z;
    uv += pd;

    float4 i = r * uv.x + u * uv.y + o + d;
    d = i - o;
    d.w = 0.0f;

    d = normalize(d);
    if (offset > 0)
    {
        _emitOffset(d, o, offset);
    }
    else
    {
        _emit(d, o);
    }
}
```

`_emit` and `_emitOffset` put the vectors into proper places in GPU memory for further processing so they are unimportant here.

For more info about my CUDA code I put here please go to [CIRT SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cirt/?source=directory).

I hope it helps.